# Why is my while loop activated, but nothing else happens?

Tags: c, input, while-loop

So right now I'm trying to mess around with stdin and an input file by doing the following:

./a.exe < input.txt

The input.txt file just has a lot of random test cases so I can see if I'm doing this right or not. I'm trying to remove some punctuation marks from my input file through the use of stdin. You will notice that I have a couple of printf's laying in there saying "here". I put that there to see if the program reaches it or not.

So whenever I run it, I type "./a.exe < input.txt", and I get "bash: input.txt: No such file or directory". So I'm like... okay, I'll just type in a couple of random inputs to see if it works. I typed in random words, and it turns out the program doesn't even hit any of the words I typed after ./a.exe.

Can anyone explain why I'm having these errors?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char textin[80], wordout[80];
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;

    printf("%d", argc);
    while (count != argc)
    {
        scanf("%s", textin);
        if (strcmp(textin, ".") == 0)
            printf("here");
        printf("here2");

        strcpy(wordout, textin);
        for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(wordout) ; i++) 
        {
            if (wordout[i] == '.'  ||  wordout[i] == ','  ||
                wordout[i] == '"'  ||  wordout[i] == ';'  ||
                wordout[i] == '!'  ||  wordout[i] == '?'  ||
                wordout[i] == '('  ||  wordout[i] == ')'  ||
                wordout[i] == ':')
            {
                for (j = i ; j < strlen(wordout) - 1 ; j++)
                    wordout[j] = wordout[j + 1];
                wordout[j] = '\0';
            }
            printf("here3");
        }
        printf("%s\n", wordout);
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try Adding complete path of input.txt and then reply!

Comment: `for (i=0; i<strlen(wordout); i++)` very very very bad and common beginer or PHP programmer mistake. `strcmp(textin,".") == 0` -> `*textin == '.'`, Also you could use a `switch` instead of the `if`.

Comment: CygWin? Otherwise, an `exe` suffix on your executables is likely to invoke derisory laughter from more seasoned UNIX devs :-)

Answer (score 3):

That first issue has nothing to do with your program, the error you're getting is a `bash` error, trying to open `input.txt` to connect to the standard input of your `a.exe` program. This happens before your code even begins to run.

You need to figure out *why* `bash` can't find your file, such as:

- are you in the correct directory?
- does the `input.txt` file actually exist?
- have you created it in such a way that there are special characters in the file name (such as `inpux<backspace>t.txt`)?

As to the other issue, you appear to be using a mish-mash of two different methods of getting information from the user.

These two methods are arguments passed to the program (`argc/v`) and standard input (`scanf()`).

It *may* be that you're running your code with something like:

```
./a.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

and expecting it to do something with them. Unfortunately, the `scanf()` inside your loop will simply wait for you to type something on the terminal so it may *seem* that it has hung.

I think you need to figure out *how* you want to present the input to the program. If it's via arguments, you would use `argv[N]` where `1 <= N < argc`. If it's via standard input, you probably don't need to concern yourself with `argc/v` at all.

Comment: Wow. Okay, so I typed in ls, and found out that my input file was actually named "input.txt.txt". Sorry for the simple mistake guys.